# Azure: The access token has been obtained from wrong audience or resource

Tags: python, azure, azure-resource-manager

Trying to create a simple task to list all resources in Azure portal. I followed the direction in the given URL and successfully received token.

http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resourcemanagement.html#authentication

However using the combination of token and superscription_id, I am getting the following error.

ERROR:

```
azure.common.AzureHttpError: {"error"{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"The access token has been obtained from wrong audience or resource '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. It should exactly match (including forward slash) with one of the allowed audiences 'https://management.core.windows.net/','https://management.azure.com/'."}}
```

I have created an application in Active directory and assigned all permission to windows active directory

Following is the code to get token:

```
def get_token_from_client_credentials(endpoint, client_id, client_secret):
    payload = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret
        # 'resource': 'https://management.core.windows.net/',
    }
    response = requests.post(endpoint, data=payload).json()
    return response['access_token']

auth_token = get_token_from_client_credentials(endpoint='https://login.microsoftonline.com/11111111111-1111-11111-1111-111111111111/oauth2/token',
             client_id='22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222',
             client_secret='test/one/year/secret/key',
```

Trying to consume this token in the following code :

```
def get_list_resource_groups(access_token, subscription_id):
    cred = SubscriptionCloudCredentials(subscription_id, access_token)
    resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(cred)
    resource_group_list = resource_client.resource_groups.list(None)
    rglist = resource_group_list.resource_groups
    return rglist
```

Answer (score 12):

> That is not impacting (its an optional parameter)

Actually, the `resource` parameter is required in [Service to Service Calls Using Client Credentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx) flow for access token, this parameter tells your application where to get token. As you need to authenticate ARM requests, you need set `'resource': 'https://management.core.windows.net/'` in `get_token_from_client_credentials()`

And we can also get the information from your error message:

> The access token has been obtained from wrong audience or resource '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. It should exactly match (including forward slash) with one of the allowed audiences 'https://management.core.windows.net/','https://management.azure.com/'

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you have this line commented out?

```
'resource': 'https://management.core.windows.net/',
```

this is the audience that you are getting the token for so you are going to need this line.

Comment: That is not impacting (its an optional parameter)